# php array delete some values and reorder

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

(added more info)
Hello I am having some trouble populating an array with php, I make a mysql query to get data between 2 dates, and these are the results:

```
"SELECT hours FROM dates WHERE id='2' AND (day BETWEEN 'TODAY' AND 'TODAY +2 DAYS') ORDER BY day ASC, hours ASC" [Seudo code]

0-> 1:data10 2:-       3:-
1-> 1:data11 2:-       3:-
2-> 1:data12 2:-       3:-
3-> 1:-      2:data23  3:-
4-> 1:-      2:data24  3:-
5-> 1:-      2:data25  3:-
6-> 1:-      2:-       3:data36
7-> 1:-      2:-       3:data37
8-> 1:-      2:-       3:data38
```

[html result from above array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2hct.png)

but what I need it is something like this:

```
0-> 1:data10  2:data23     3:data36
1-> 1:data11  2:data24     3:data37
2-> 1:data12  2:data25     3:data38
```

[html result with reorder array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4umNi.png)

And also if just one (or 2) column/s have a value the other/s value/s should be "-"

```
0-> 1:data10  2:data20     3:data30
1-> 1:-11     2:data21     3:-31
2-> 1:data12  2:-22        3:data32
```

Is there a way to delete or add the "-" from the array and reorder the other values and keys?
Thanks!
PD: please let me know if I missed some data.

Comment: can u provide your code?Means what you have done

Comment: remove "-" from an array isn't too hard, but the problem is how you wants to rearrange your data into new array. From your example I can't tell where is the 0-> 2:data or 0->3:data from.

Comment: if you provide your actual query then it might provide some context of what you are trying to achieve - at the moment there is too little information to provide a meaningful answer

Comment: Hello, question edited with more info, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After remove some index from array and you want to get array in same index format or say reindex try with

```
 array_values($array);
```

This array function rearrange the array index. Enjoy Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've written following code for you problem. You want result 's inner array to have 3 keys that's why i've written "if($s_key >= 3)" , you can update it as per need. Currently you don't want '-' that's why i've written "if($val != '-')" you can add more conditions as per your need.

Thanks.

Happy Coding

```html
//sample data

$data = array (array('111','-','222'),array('3333','-','444'),array('-','-','444'),array('4545','77','444'),array('-','454','444'),array('-','98','444'));
$formatted_data = array();
$f_key = $s_key = 0;
foreach($data as $arr_key => $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        if($val != '-'){  
            $formatted_data[$f_key][$s_key] = $val;
            $s_key++;
            if($s_key >= 3){             
                $s_key = 0;
                $f_key++;
            }        
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($formatted_data);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the code concatenate data for array key like this 0->7:008:009:00, at 1-> hourshourshours, I'm trying to build something like 0->[1]7:00[2]8:00[3]9:00, thanks regards

Comment: i've edited my answer removed testing code line from it. 
Output :
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "111"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "222"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "3333"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "444"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "444"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "4545"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "77"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "444"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "454"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "444"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "98"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "444"
  }
}

Comment: Output array : 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111
            [1] => 222
            [2] => 3333
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 444
            [1] => 444
            [2] => 4545
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 77
            [1] => 444
            [2] => 454
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 444
            [1] => 98
            [2] => 444
        )
)

this is what you want buddy ?

Comment: Hi! it is fine your code, but the reorder should be in columns, for example first position into array should be (111,77,222), second (3333,454,444), third(4545,98,444).... please let me know if explain myself, thanks! regards

Answer (score 0):

first delete array values by this code :

```
 unset($array[$index]);
```

then re order like this :

```
array_values($array);
```